# Selenium IEDriver "Error retrieving window with handle current"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Hello to all,**

I use Selenium with all sorts of drivers, but today when I used the IEDriver for the first time I got the exception: `"Error retrieving window with handle current"`

**My code is:**

```
private static IWebDriver driver;

InternetExplorerDriverService driverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
InternetExplorerOptions IEOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();

driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.LibraryExtractionPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
driverService.Port = 8080;

IEOptions.EnableNativeEvents = true;
IEOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
IEOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(driverService, IEOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToWait));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ImplicitlyWaitTime));

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("something");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); //*
```

It loads the website and when I call Maximize the program throws an exception (after that I can't do anything with that driver object [window handler lost])

This happens only with the IE Driver (I tried the 32 and 64 bit versions).

I am using the latest version of Selenium.

Thanks.

Comment: have you got javascript enabled in the I.E. Browser properties.

Comment: i didn't changed nothing since it's worked. maybe update ?!#...

Comment: No all set like it was, js enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For I.E. it needs to be configured correctly. Ensure you have followed the instructions correctly for I.E. to work. It needs more setup than the other browsers [I.E. Selenium Configuration](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)